# Syntax - how to add eq(i) to variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm desperately trying to combine `element` with the index-selector `eq()`.
Is there anything wrong with the syntax?

```
function setVisibleRange(element) {
    for ( -- something with i -- ) {};
     $(element:eq(i).show();
};

setVisibleRange($("ul li"));
```

Btw, is there a better way to adress a Range of elements? Something like `eq(0, 4)`? The for-loop is just a workaround.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `eq` with element using `.` operator,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/chD5R/)**

```
function setVisibleRange(element) {
    for ( i=0; i < element.length; i++)
        element.eq(i).show();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function setVisibleRange(element) {
    for (var i=element.length; i--;) {
        element.eq(i).show();
    }
}

setVisibleRange($("ul li"));
```

for something like `eq(0, 4)`, I would do :

```
$("ul li:lt(5)").show();
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need it more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

About combining variables and text:

```
$(element + ':eq(' + i + ')')
```

Also you can use custom filter functions. [jQuery filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)